# What are the chkconfig directives (classic style) into init.d scripts?

Tags: centos, rhel, init-script

To ask my question, I must first clarify the context.

Every init script in `/etc/init.d` (on RedHat and Centos distros) is prepared to be managed with the `chkconfig` command-line tool utility.

This tool manages the symlinks in `/etc/rc[0-6].d`, understand runlevels and permit to add and remove init scripts from the set that is meant to run for every runlevel.  ([see man chkconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chkconfig)). NOTE: it does **not** start **nor** stop the services / daemons but it permit a simpler management of what is "on" and what is "off" in every runlevel.

According to man, to achieve this, every init script in `/etc/init.d` have to contain exactly two directives on a commended line (`chkconfig:` and `description:`, see manpage ) or a [LSB-style init stanza](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/initscrcomconv.html). But let put aside for a moment this LSB-tyles stanzas (which have been introduced relatively recently) and are much more descriptive than the original chkconfig "format" (this topic can be good for other questions).

Out of curiosity, I have run on my RedHat boxes (5.2 & 6.1) this command to examine the init scripts:

```
find /etc/init.d/ -ls -execdir head -n20 {} \;
```

and I have see other (possibly undocumented) directives:

- `# processname:`
- `# pidfile:`
- `# config:`
- `# Author:`

These are in the comment lines and look the same as the official directives (`chkconfig:` and `description:`).

Does anyone know if these are `chkconfig` directives or they are only some nice formatted comments?

If these are directive too what do they mean?

There are some reference? I wasn't able to find any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation for these directives is in `/usr/share/doc/initscripts-*/sysvinitfiles`. Except for "Author", which is non-standard.